# Using Excel & Access Together passing a variable from excel to access

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

In excel I have a linked table to a access table "tbl_Output"

Currently there is a manual step that before I run a excel macro I have to go into the database and open up a create table query and manual enter a criteria and run. Call it Field "Vendor Name"

This vendor name exists in the excel document. Is it possible to declare that variable in excel, pass it to access and run the create table query using that variable as its criteria.

The task gets run for many vendors so if I can automate this step I can create a loop to go through all vendors.

I have tried a workaround by having a linked pivot table to the data source that the create table query is based off then filtering in the excel pivot table itself but due to the large amount of data the refresh takes too long.

Apologies if this is something obvious. Coding vba with access is something im not familiar with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% on the question that is being asked but I'm gonna take a shot at it.  The code below will take a list of Vendor Names [Vendor Ids] and will loop through the list executing a create table query for each of the Vendor Ids that contains the information for that specific Vendor

```
Sub umCreateDBTables()
    Dim DBPath As String ' Path to the database with the information
    Dim DBPath2 As String ' Path to the database to store the newly created tables in
    Dim xlCell As Range
    Dim sSQL As String
    Dim DB As DAO.Database
    Dim VenID As String
    Dim i As Integer
        DBPath = "C:\DB_Temp\AccessDB_A.accdb"
        DBPath2 = "C:\DB_Temp\AccessDB_B.accdb"
        Set DB = OpenDatabase(DBPath, True, False)
        Set xlCell = Range("A2") ' Assumes that this is the beginning of the column with your vendor ids
        Do Until xlCell.Value = "" ' Loops through the list of vendor ids until it gets to an empty cell
            VenID = "v_" & xlCell.Value ' would be best to feed this through a function to strip out any invalid db field name characters
            sSQL = "SELECT T1.F1, T1.F2, T1.F3, INTO " & VenID & " IN '" & DBPath2 & "' FROM T1 WHERE (((T1.F1)='" & xlCell.Value & "'));"
            For i = DB.TableDefs.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1 ' Cycle through the list of database objects [tables, queries, etc....]
                If DB.TableDefs(i).Name = VenID Then ' If the vendor table already exists in the DB, delete it so it can be recreated
                    DB.TableDefs.Delete (VenID)
                End Select
            Next i
            DB.Execute sSQL ' Run the SQL to create the vendor table
            Set xlCell = xlCell.Offset(1, 0) ' move down to the next row
        Loop
        DB.Close
        Set DB = Nothing
        Set xlCell = Nothing
End Sub
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much Glenn G. This really help solve the issue I was having.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much Glenn G

The code you provided was extremely helpful and put me in the right direction.

I was having run-time issues with the DAO even with references added though but worked around it.

Code I got to work was:

```
Sub UpdateDatabase()
Dim DBPath As String
Dim xlcell As Range
Dim sSQL As String, stProvider As String
Dim DB As New ADODB.Connection
    DBPath = "C:\Temp\Data.accdb"
    stProvider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    With DB
        .ConnectionString = DBPath
        .Provider = stProvider
        .Open
    End With
    Set xlcell = Sheet3.Range("X2")
    Do Until xlcell.Value = ""
        venid = xlcell.Value
        sSQL = "SELECT ALL * INTO tbl_Output FROM qry_Data WHERE (((qry_Data.VendorName)='" & xlcell.Value & "'));"
        DB.Execute "DROP TABLE tbl_Output;"
        DB.Execute sSQL
        Set xlcell = xlcell.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
    DB.Close
    Set DB = Nothing
    Set xlcell = Nothing
```

Thank you again for your help.

Regards

Richard